# Symfony returns null on template render

Tags: php, json, symfony

I've been working on steam web api and making requests. A couple of the api methods that I've decided to use are these:

'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/?format=json'
'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?format=json'
'https://api.steampowered.com/IGCVersion_440/GetServerVersion/v0001/?format=json'

These were taken from this link: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamWebAPIUtil/GetSupportedAPIList/v0001/?format=json

I've tried them all as a regular url link on browsers and they return fine.

On Symfony, I have this code on my :

```
/**
 * @Route("/getClientVersion440")
 */
public function getClientVersion440()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.steampowered.com/IGCVersion_440/GetClientVersion/v0001/?format=json',
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    return $this->render(
        'custom/test.html.twig',
        array('content' => json_decode($content))
    );
}

/**
 * @Route("/getSteamAppsListv1")
 */
public function getSteamAppsListv1()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/?format=json',
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    return $this->render(
        'custom/test.html.twig',
        array('content' => json_decode($content))
    );
}

/**
 * @Route("/getSteamAppsListv2")
 */
public function getSteamAppsListv2()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?format=json',
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    return $this->render(
        'custom/test.html.twig',
        array('content' => json_decode($content))
    );
}
```

And on my twig template, I have a custom one based on base.html.twig where I'm displaying the data as follows:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="results">
            {{dump(content)}}
        </div>

    </div>
```

The first one works fine on symfony but the other 2 returns null. I'm fairly new to symfony, but I've been looking at other posts to check for issues and viewed the profiler to troubleshoot but so far, I don't know what is happening. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: check the application error log in app/logs/dev.log and webserver error logs for errors.

Comment: I've checked the dev.log and these are the last few lines pertaining to the error:  [2015-11-19 20:55:30] request.INFO: Matched route "app_steamapi_getsteamappslistv2". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\steamApi::getSteamAppsListv2","_route":"app_steamapi_getsteamappslistv2"},"request_uri":"https://steamlode.com/app_dev.php/getSteamAppsListv2"} []  On the apache web server, theres nothing on the error logs. The last entry was on November 8.  

    PHP logs doesn't say anything either regarding what's wrong with the request.

Comment: Your third URL, https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/IGCVersion_440/GetServerVersion/v0001/?format=json gives me a 404

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, it's fixed now.

Comment: does content without json_decode also returns null ?

Comment: If I do return the content without json_decode, then it returns "false" since the data being received from the curl call is in json format.